# I am looking to retrieve email of current user after fetching their userUID from the attendance collection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I know this is normally done by checking who is logged in and using this code.

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null){
        username.setText("Welcome " +user.getEmail());
    }
```

But in the following code I am retrieving the userUID from my attendance collection on cloud firestore and am looking to use that to get the email associated with that userUID.

Here is my code:

```
   public void viewAttendance(View v) {
    attendanceRef2.orderBy("sessionID", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            String data = "";

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Attendance attendance = documentSnapshot.toObject(Attendance.class);

                String sessionID = attendance.getSessionID();
                String attendanceUID = attendance.getUserUID();



                data+= "Session ID: " +sessionID+ "\n" + "Student: " +attendanceUID+ "\n\n";
                textViewData.setText(data);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that the email address is stored somewhere in the documents in the collection?

Comment: no the email address associated with the userUID from the attendance collection is stored in Firebase Authentication

Comment: Please add the database structure and indicate which email address you want to get and how. Please responde with @.

Comment: One user's account can't just reach into any arbitrary user's accounts to get that other user's email (for privacy reasons).  You have to choose to make that data available to others by writing it to your database and allowing access to it.

Answer (score 0):

So, u r saying, you want to retrieve email addresses from attendenceUID(i.e.,userId).

If yes,

You cannot retrieve the data of all authenticated user from Firebase Authentication, however you can only get the data of current user.

To get data of all users u need to use [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users)

Here is an example to it :

```
UserRecord userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(uid);
// See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
System.out.println("Successfully fetched user data: " + userRecord.getUid());
```

In your case what u can do is :

```
UserRecord userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(attendanceUID);
String email = userRecord.getEmail();
```

Or u can use List to store them all.